How can i config LLD macro which contans special characters in discovery item prototypes? It will be escaped auto by zabbix
My discover rule json like this:
[
{
"id": 154,
"application_name": "/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.90/",
"application_user": "webapp",
"application_type": "BatchService",
"application_log": "/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.90/logs/catalina.out",
"err_ignore_key": "sceno [793]||sceno [794]",
}
]
I config $.err_ignore_key to {#ERR_IGNORE_KEY} LLD macro.
i want to use this LLD macro in a item prototypes Preprocessing:
enter image description here
But '[' ']' '|' will be escaped auto by zabbix :sceno [793]||sceno [794]
enter image description here
Actually i want "sceno [793]||sceno [794]" in Preprocessing step ,how can i fit it?
Or how can i change my json string ,zabbix will not escape '|' auto.
